# kernel symbol marked with "T" in /proc/kallsyms is not exported

Tags: linux, module, kernel, export, symbols

Symbol `machine_power_off` is marked with "T" in `/proc/kallsyms`:

```
$ grep -w machine_power_off /proc/kallsyms 
ffffffff8102391b T machine_power_off
```

But it is [not exported](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=machine_power_off). Is "T" in kallsyms necessary and sufficient for a symbol to be exported? Is being exported necessary and sufficient for using in other modules?

My module using it is compiled with a warning:

```
WARNING: "machine_power_off" [/path/to/module.ko] undefined!
```

On host machine (3.2.0-4-amd64) I can load this module, but on VirtualBox (3.16.0-4-amd64) it produces the following message:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module module.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Why is this module loaded in my host system, but not in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mark "T" in `/proc/kallsyms` means that symbol is globally visible, and can be used in other **kernel's code** (e.g. by drivers, compiled **built-in**).

But for being usable in **kernel module's code**, symbol is needed to be exported using `EXPORT_SYMBOL` or similar. List of exported symbols is maintained separately from list of all symbols in the kernel.

Exported symbols can be found in file `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/build/Module.symvers`.

(this file should exist for possibility to build kernel modules against given kernel).

Comment: Is it possible to sidestep "kernel-only" limitation with `dlopen` and `dlsym`?

Comment: @jww: In Linux kernel world, "search symbol" functionality is known as function `kallsyms_lookup_name()`. Its usage is described in the [mdd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32968387/3440745).

Answer (score 7):

To use kernel symbols that are global, but not exported (such as the `machine_power_off` symbol that you mention), you can use `kallsyms_lookup` in your module code:

```c
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>

static void (*machine_power_off_p)(void);
machine_power_off_p = (void*) kallsyms_lookup_name("machine_power_off");
```

Now you can call the `machine_power_off` function via the `machine_power_off_p` pointer:

```c
(*machine_power_off_p)();
```

Comment: this would only work if `kallsyms_lookup_name` is also exported (some versions dont have it exported)

Comment: One of the errors reported is about conflicting types.

Comment: It's pretty much OK actually, nothing special , they just dropped a "_p".
Don't forget to define CONFIG_KALLSYMS .