# getname is an unknown symbol in Linux

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, kernel-module

I am trying to test `getname` in a kernel module. My code for the hijacked system call looks like:

```
asmlinkage long (*real_open)(const char __user *, int, int);

struct filename *getname_filename;

asmlinkage long hijacked_open(const char __user *filename, int flags, int mode) {
    getname_filename = getname(filename);
    printk("Opened: %s", getname_filename->name);
    return real_open(filename, flags, mode);
}
```

The code compiles without any problems, but when I insert the module using `insmod`, I get the error `Unknown symbol in module` with AND without the `printk` line. But in `/proc/kallsyms`, I can find `getname`, so it IS exported. Why can't I use it and how can I use it?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `But in /proc/kallsyms, I can find getname, so it IS exported.` - No, existing of the symbol in `/proc/kallsyms` doesn't mean that this symbol is available for *kernel module*. See that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965535/kernel-symbol-marked-with-t-in-proc-kallsyms-is-not-exported

Comment: @Tsyvarev And how does one determine if a symbol is exported or not?

Comment: See my answer to the referenced question.