# How do I access any kernel symbol in a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am wanting to use the function `getname` in my kernel module. It is not exported. Since I am running into this problem right now, I would like to know how to access and use any kernel symbol that is not exported. I figure that the steps necessary to use one will differ depending what the symbol is, so I'd like to see how it would be done for a type (e.g., a struct), a variable, a table of pointers (like the system call table), and a function. How can these be done in either of these cases:

- When I know the address of the symbol from `System.map` or `/proc/kallsyms`.
- When I know the name of the symbol and want to use `kallsyms_lookup_name` in retrieving it.

I currently know how to hijack system calls and this requires declaring something like

```
asmlinkage <return_type> (*<name_for_system_call>)(<the types of the its arguments separated by commas>);
```

Would something like that be used? In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32968387/1953537) answer to another question, the example presented by the poster is

```
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>

static void (*machine_power_off_p)(void);
machine_power_off = (void*) kallsyms_lookup_name("machine_power_off");
```

But what if the symbol returns a pointer? Would I place an asterisk to the left of `(*machine_power_off_p)`?

Comment: "Would I place an asterisk to the left of the first set of parentheses?" Which parentheses? There are lots of parentheses in your question. So are you asking how to invoke a function pointer? Google should be able to tell you that. For example: [How do function pointers in C work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: @kaylum The first set in the example right above that question.

Comment: `But what if the symbol returns a pointer?` - Then replace *left* `void` in the example with returning type (e.g., `struct filename *`). The question is actually about usage of pointer-to-functions, as kaylum have noticed.

Answer (score 4):

`#include <linux/fs.h>` declares `extern struct filename *getname(const char __user *);`. A pointer to this function has type `struct filename *(*)(const char __user *)`. If declaring a variable of that type, the variable name goes after the `*` in `(*)`. So you can declare a variable of that type and assign the return value of `kallsyms_lookup_name("getname")` to it as follows:

```
static struct filename *(*getname_p)(const char __user *);

/* within a function body... */
getname_p = (struct filename *(*)(const char __user *))
            kallsyms_lookup_name("getname");
```

For your other case where you want to use a numeric address, just replace the `kallsyms_lookup_name` function call with the actual number (`kallsyms_lookup_name` returns the symbol value as a number anyway).

**EDIT 2021-01-19**

The GCC `typeof` extension can be used to copy the prototype of `getname` from `#include <linux/fs.h>` to the `getname_p` pointer as follows:

```
#include <linux/fs.h>

static typeof(&getname) getname_p;

/* within a function body... */
getname_p = (typeof(&getname))kallsyms_lookup_name("getname");
```

**EDIT 2021-05-17**

From the 5.7 kernel onwards `kallsyms_lookup_name` and `kallsyms_on_each_symbol` are no longer exported to loadable kernel modules.

Comment: Is there anyway to define the function as `getname` instead of `getname_p`? Can it be done in such a way as to not require looking up the original function's declaration?

Comment: @Melab The function pointer variable cannot be called `getname` unless it is declared in an inner scope (such as within a function body) because it would conflict with the declaration of the `getname` function declared by `#include <linux/fs.h>`. However, you can simplify the declaration of the `getname_p` variable and the casting of the return value of `kallsyms_lookup_name` by making use of the GCC `typeof` extension, as shown in my edited answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing not exported function doesn't differ from accessing exported functions, except that you can't resolve its address in kernel. You can do trick like this:

```
static void (*your_func)(void);
your_func=0xhex_addr;
```

or for struct

```
strucr your_struct{int i;double j} *stru;
stru=0xhex_addr;
```

Type of a pointer just defines how many bytes would be read or written from or to pointer's address.

For structure or variable hex address even may reside in kernel code segment, but you'll get segmentation fault if you'll try to write something to that struct or var - reading would be legit. And one more thing... when doing this trick with structure don't forget about structure data alignment.