# Is it possible to call sys_mprotect from a kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mprotect

I'm writing a kernel module that needs to change page permissions for a task. Normally, the task would just call mprotect and set the permissions. As I understand Linux kernel has `sys_mprotect`, which performs the actual system call.

Is it possible that my Linux kernel module calls `sys_mprotect`? I cannot seem to find a kernel API that allows that.

Comment: Let's back up a second. Why do you think your kernel module needs to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it's possible to call `sys_mprotect` in a kernel module as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431194/how-do-i-access-any-kernel-symbol-in-a-kernel-module/40513836#40513836) using `kallsyms_lookup_name`.

An alternative way for achieving some of the page permission changes is to directly call kernel APIs such as `pte_wrprotect`, which will clear the write permissions from a PTE.