# ERROR: modpost: "kallsyms_on_each_symbol"

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to create a kernel module that changes the PID of a process. I searched in google and came across many articles that references this github

```
https://github.com/gravit0/changepid/blob/master/module/main.c
```

For the above github i took the following parts that should be responsible for the PID change.

```
static void* find_sym( const char *sym ) {  // find address kernel symbol sym 
   static unsigned long faddr = 0;          // static !!! 
   // ----------- nested functions are a GCC extension --------- 
   int symb_fn( void* data, const char* sym, struct module* mod, unsigned long addr ) { 
      if( 0 == strcmp( (char*)data, sym ) ) { 
         faddr = addr; 
         return 1; 
      } 
      else return 0; 
   }; 
   // -------------------------------------------------------- 
   kallsyms_on_each_symbol( symb_fn, (void*)sym ); 
   return (void*)faddr; 
}
```

```
static asmlinkage void (*change_pidR)(struct task_struct *task, enum pid_type type,
        struct pid *pid);
static asmlinkage struct pid* (*alloc_pidR)(struct pid_namespace *ns);
```

```
 change_pidR = find_sym("change_pid");
 alloc_pidR = find_sym("alloc_pid");
```

On compilation i get the following error on the kallsyms_on_each_symbol() function

```
MODPOST /home/anastasis/projects/Module.symvers
ERROR: modpost: "kallsyms_on_each_symbol" [home/anastasis/projects/change_pid.ko] undefined!
```

How do i fix this?

PS. As a potential fix i installed a new kernel on a vm and i made sure that the option about kallsyms is enabled, but i still get the same ERROR.

Comment: Do you include the header <linux/kallsyms.h> ?

Comment: yes there is no include missing i have made sure of that

Comment: then, I would check if the related CONFIGs were not enabled in the kernel I used. Maybe you need to check CONFIG_KALLSYM or CONFIG_LIVEPATCH? or maybe kallsyms_on_each_symbol is in the scope of any other CONFIGs?

Comment: where do i check those configs? I have tried to find the CONFIG_KALLSYM with no success.

Comment: Why not  link your module with change_pid and alloc_pid?

Comment: How do i do that? How do i link my module with those 2 functions?

Comment: Since Linux kernel 5.7, the function `kallsyms_on_each_symbol` is no longer accessible for modules (that is, it is not EXPORT-ed). See e.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40513836/3440745). A functionality which allows to circumvent restriction of non-EXPORTed symbols has gone away: https://lwn.net/Articles/813350/.