# how to flush tlb entry in kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I want to write a function in my kernel module to invalidate the physical page mapping of a virtual address. However, I don't know how to flush the tlb entry of the page of the virtual address.
I try to use "flush_tlb_range" in my module code. However, it reports "implicit declaration of function ‘flush_tlb_range’".

Here is a snippet in my code

```C
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <asm/tlb.h>
#include <asm/tlbflush.h>

u64 mypool_get_page(u64 gfn, bool write_fault, bool *writable){
  u64 kvm_hva;
  struct mm_struct *mm = current->mm; 
  struct vm_area_struct *vma = current->mm->mmap;
  unsigned int level;
  pte_t *ptep;

  kvm_hva = map_lookup(index);
  
  ....

  //invalid kvm_hva in page table
  ptep = lookup_address(kvm_hva, &level);
  if (ptep) {
    pte_clear(mm, kvm_hva, ptep);     
    flush_tlb_range(vma,kvm_hva, kvm_hva+PAGE_SIZE);
  }

  ...

}
```

Here is my Makefile

```makefile
mypool-objs := pool-main.o maptable.o
obj-m += mypool.o
KERNEL := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build 
PWD :=$(shell pwd) 
modules :
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL) M=$(PWD) modules
.PHONEY:clean
clean :
    rm -rf *.o *.ko
```

Can someone teach me how to invalidate tlb in kernel modules?

I also tried to use ‘flush_tlb_mm_range’. However, it also reports
implicit declaration of function ‘flush_tlb_mm_range’.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70930059/3889449

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve the goal depending on what you want to achieve.

### First Option

If you are on x86 you can flush the TLB entry of the currently running CPU with

```C
asm volatile("invlpg (%0)" ::"r" (addr) : "memory");
```

However, this does **not** ensure coherency between the remaining cores of the system. You would need to perform a TLBSHOOTDOWN and manually do the IPI's to sync the TLB. For other architectures, such as ARM64 this is not required.

### Second Option

Change the Linux kernel and export the symbol of the function you want to use. This is a pretty dirty way and should not be done in production, but if it is just for testing this should be sufficient.

```C
EXPORT_SYMBOL(flush_tlb_range)
```

### Third Option

Use `kallsyms_lookup_name` to find the address of the function. Here is an example kernel module. Note that there is a problem with IBT enabled and AFAIK there is currently no solution to this problem [stackoverflow-discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170020/calling-kallsyms-lookup-name-found-in-a-module-causes-a-segementation-fault).

```C
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <asm/tlbflush.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/mm_types.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/version.h>


#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(5, 7, 0)
#define KPROBE_KALLSYMS_LOOKUP 1
typedef unsigned long (*kallsyms_lookup_name_t)(const char *name);
kallsyms_lookup_name_t kallsyms_lookup_name_func;
#define kallsyms_lookup_name kallsyms_lookup_name_func

static struct kprobe kp = {
    .symbol_name = "kallsyms_lookup_name"
};
#endif


void (*flush_tlb_mm_range_func)(struct mm_struct *, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned int, bool);

/*
 * Init function of our module
 */
static int __init init_custom(void) {
    /*
     * Dirty workaround to get kallsyms_lookup_name address, since it is not exported anymore
    */ 
    register_kprobe(&kp);
    #ifdef CONFIG_X86_KERNEL_IBT
    printk("IBT IS ENABLED\n");
    return -ENXIO;
    #else
    printk("IBT IS DISABLED\n");
    kallsyms_lookup_name = (kallsyms_lookup_name_t) kp.addr;
    #endif

    printk("kallsyms_lookup_name address: %px\n", kallsyms_lookup_name);

    unregister_kprobe(&kp);

    if(!unlikely(kallsyms_lookup_name)) {
      pr_alert("Could not retrieve kallsyms_lookup_name address\n");
      return -ENXIO;
    }

    // get flush_tlb_mm_range address
    flush_tlb_mm_range_func = (void *)kallsyms_lookup_name("flush_tlb_mm_range");
    printk("flush_tlb_mm_range address: %p\n", flush_tlb_mm_range_func);
    if (!flush_tlb_mm_range_func) {
        pr_alert("Could not retrieve flush_tlb_mm_range function\n");
        return -ENXIO;
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
 * Exit function of our module.
 */
static void __exit exit_custom(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hasta la vista, Kernel!\n");
}

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("WIP");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

module_init(init_custom);
module_exit(exit_custom);
```

Comment: The kernel module is not written very clean, feel free to clean it up (I might to it at some point as well)