# Alternative to the GPL *find_symbol* method in Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a proprietary *Linux* module which might be loaded before or after a second proprietary module that contain the function **foo**.

I would like my first module, when being configured **dynamically**, to lookup for the second's module symbol **foo**, and if found to call it.

The general idea (in loose syntax) is this:

```
/* check if the module/symbol can be found */    
module, foo_cb = lookup_for_a_symbol("foo");

if (foo_cb && module) {
    /* increment the refcnt to make sure the module will not be unloaded */
    module_try_get(module);

    foo_cb(my_params);

    /* release the module */ 
    module_put(module);
}
```

I found a function in module.c that does something like this called **find_symbol**, however it is GPL.

Any non-GPL alternative for dynamic symbol lookup ?

Thanks.

Comment: A good discussion is at [Kernel symbol marked with “T” in /proc/kallsyms is not exported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32965535/608639). It introduces `kallsyms_lookup_name` and `kallsyms_lookup` but they are probably GPL, too. Another related one is [Unknown symbol flush_tlb_all (err 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52082603/608639).

Comment: @jww - Yep...GPL also :(

Comment: It's possible, from userspace to parse /proc/kallsyms, get the symbol and the module, and send the addresses to the module. but this seems hacky, and error prone, if for example, the module was removed since

Comment: Create a GPL helper module, which exports a function (using EXPORT_SYMBOL instead of EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL) to look up your symbol, which can be then used in your module with proprietary licence

Comment: That's kind of clever @Ctx. It seems like that should run afoul of some versions of GPL. I believe that is what kind of happened with the situation at [Being honest with MODULE_LICENSE](https://lwn.net/Articles/82305/) on LWN, but it was deemed OK. The symbol helper module does seem to run afoul of the *"... it is not an attempt to get around the kernel's simplistic access control mechanism [for a symbol]"* discussed in the article, but I am not sure what happens next.

Comment: @jww Yes, I think it might be problematik when re-exporting functions as a whole in such "licence-adapter-modules", but probably doing such a narrow task as looking up a single symbol isn't really infringing the licence. But IANAL of course

Comment: @Ctx but, we now need to make sure that the GPL proxy module is loaded..isn't this moving the same problem to a different place ?

Comment: @ItayMarom Hm, not really... You just install both modules, depmod and modprobe will take care of loading it automatically

Comment: @ctx but if I can make sure it will always be loaded at startup, it can provide dynamic lookup...good idea

Comment: I'm prepared to argue that a kernel image dump is GPL even if the original modules weren't.

Answer (score 0):

But your module does not export GPL symbols, so this should not be a problem. The only problem is if you want to be able to load proprietary module bar without loading foo.

Module foo should use `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` to export anything that will be used by bar.

If you need conditional dynamic linking, then add a third module to do this, which calls bar with the symbol from foo and use `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` in both foo and bar to make the necessary symbols available to module foobar.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I know it is a relatively old question, but I recently had the same need and I used a pretty obvious solution without creating a GPL helper module that nobody mentioned here, so I think it is worth mentioning.

[scnprintf](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-scnprintf.html) is non GPL, and it supports `%pf` or `%pF` format that does the symbol resolution you need. See [printk formats](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt)